# Laplacian filter in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, filter, filtering

I want to compute the output image by first dividing the image into 8*8 blocks and applying laplace filter separately and combine them but I am not getting the correct output
Here is the code:

```
I=imread('moon.tif');
figure;
imshow(I);
title('Original Image');
g=[0 1 0;1 -4 1;0 1 0];
[N, M] = size(I);
output = zeros(N,M);
for i=1:8:N
    for j=1:8:M
        a = min(i+7,N);
        b = min(j+7,M);
        img = I(i:a,j:b);
        r = imfilter(im2double(img),g);
        output(i:a,j:b) = im2double(img)-r;
    end
end
figure;
imshow(output);
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/761zB.jpg)

Here is the output I am getting blocks by blocks discontinuous
But when I run this code

```
I=imread('moon.tif');
figure;
imshow(I);
title('Original Image');
g=[0 1 0;1 -4 1;0 1 0];
resp=imfilter(I,g);
output = I-resp;
figure;
imshow(output);
title('Sharpened image');
```

[Output1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB8iU.jpg)

I am getting the correct output. How to get this by dividing the image into 8x8 blocks and combining them

Comment: you need to set the boundary conditions of your filter. What happens when the filter needs values outside the image? In your first case, notice that that is whre you have issues, the white bands are half the size of your filter.

Comment: You cannot filter this way. Not sure what it is that you saw and try to replicate, but it is not this. If you want to process your image in small sections, you need to discard the edges of the sections before gluing them back together. When you create the sections you therefore need to make them a bit larger, so that they overlap, abs when you remove the edges they will still cover the whole image.

Comment: @CrisLuengo so I want to consider more image patch and discard and combine them can you specify exactly how much to take

Comment: The Laplace kernel you apply is 3x3, meaning that it extends past the image by 1 pixel on all sides. This you need to make your patches 1 pixel larger on all sides, without increasing the step size in your loop: `img=I(i:a+2,j:b+2)`, and after filtering: `img(2:end-1,2:end-1)`.